# Detect pushd depth in bash?

Tags: bash, pushd

I would like to be able to programmaticly detect when my `pushd` stack is non-empty, within a bash shell.  Is there any way to detect this?

Something akin to $SHLVL would be nice.  But so far, the only solution I've found is to wrap `pushd` and `popd` with aliases that parse the output of the originals to detect the depth.  While that would work, it doesn't feel particularly elegant.  (Clearly, the information is stored somewhere in the environment.)

My reason is, I wish to adorn my bash prompt with a pushd depth-count, when this is the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check `DIRSTACK` length:

```
$ [[ ${#DIRSTACK[@]} -gt 1 ]] && echo dir stack non-empty
```

Note that you can not use this method if `DIRSTACK` is unset.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that, the first time I grep'd the output of `set`.  But sure enough, there it is.   The only problem I see is, even though I'm currently 4 pushd's deep,  I currently see `DIRSTACK=()`

Comment: @RyanV.Bissell: You must use `dirs` to list the content of `DIRSTACK` or `printf '%s\n' "${DIRSTACK[@]}"`

Comment: What happens if `DIRSTACK` is unset?

Comment: @Wildcard: it lose its special meaning, read bash documentation for more details

Answer (score 2):

```
depth=$( ( $(dirs -v | wc -l) -1) )
```

is another, inferior solution.

Comment: It will fail if directory name contains newline.

Comment: You're right, I didn't think about that.  But I can only wish ill upon those who put newlines in directory names.